# Rotating a sphere so that clicked point is Vector toward the camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have searched around for an answer to this question and found two answers which are either old or do not have THREE related code.

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184589/rotating-a-sphere-a-to-b-point-on-itself) and [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474185/threejs-rotate-sphereglobe-to-another-pointcity-on-the-sphere-itself?rq=1)

What I want to happen is have the clicked point be pointing toward the camera!

```
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    var point = intersects[0].point;
    //console.log(point);

    var a = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
    var b = point.normalize();

    var rotationAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    rotationAxis.crossVectors(b, a);
    var dot = a.dot(b);
    var angle = Math.acos(dot);

    var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    var dest = quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(rotationAxis, angle);
    sphere.setRotationFromQuaternion(dest);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have been trying to convert the math from the first answer to threejs, it's almost going to the right place but out by some degrees, where am I going wrong?

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6hfxng8n/2)

**Initial position - 0,0,1**
[image: initial]

**After clicking on a point**
[image]

Comment: I think this can be accomplished by using the lookAt function (assume your sphere default facing is +z). Looking from the center of sphere towards the direction of the point you clicked.

Comment: Then it seems to me your second picture is working as intended?

Comment: Is what you are looking for a function that can return a rotational change from direction A to direction B? I have something that MIGHT work. But its not strictly THREE.

Comment: Yeah that's what my code in the question is supposed to be doing, it's going the right way but not accurate enough. I wanted to use Quaternion so that I can animate with slerp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is finding a rotation that takes you from the direction from center to the clicked point to the direction from center to camera. An implementation here: [Finding quaternion representing the rotation from one vector to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171849/finding-quaternion-representing-the-rotation-from-one-vector-to-another)

```
    var z = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);             
    var point = continent.position.clone().normalize();
    earthContainer.localToWorld(point.clone()));

    var q = new THREE.Quaternion();
    q.setFromUnitVectors(point, z);
    earthContainer.setRotationFromQuaternion(q);
```

It turns out THREE js does implement this as q.setFromUnitVectors(u, v);. I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6hfxng8n/4/ and it is almost exactly the answer to the first answer you linked to. Yet it is approximately working (click slightly right -> sphere rotates left etc) but something is off. I cant figure out why.

Comment: I don't know how to get q.xyz into the quaternion.

Comment: q.x = a.x; q.y =  a.y; q.z = a.z;